# How do I make a string a string array?

Tags: java, arrays

What I'm trying to do is transform something like this: `"The Three Pigs"` into an array like this:

```
Array[0]="The"
Array[1]="Three"
Array[2]="Pigs"
```

The string class doesn't have a method for that and I cant figure out how to do it myself
The split doesn't seem to work for my purpose. Example code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetNumber();
}

private static void GetNumber() {
    System.out.println("Enter your words.");
    Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
    String O=S.next();
    String[] A=O.split(" ");
    for(int Y=0;A.length>Y;Y++){
        System.out.println(A[Y]);
    }
}

}
```

This code would output The if i put in The Little Pigs

Comment: Have you tried printing O? Are you sure you're using Scanner correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String text = "The Three Pigs";
String[] array = text.split(" ");
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to let the user to enter a line of text rather than a single word, then use:

```
String O = S.nextLine();
```

instead of:

```
String O = S.next();
```

Comment: That seems to delete everything past the, thats why i made the post

Comment: Are you sure you have the right string? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: @user1357527 what do you get if you try what is said in this answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the split method as follows

```
String[] arrString = s.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 3):

See [the split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on the String class.

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] theArray = "The Three Pigs".split(" ");
```

As for your updated question, change your scanner from `.next()` to `.nextLine()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Enter your words." );
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        String O = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println( O );
        String[] A = O.split( " " );
        for ( int Y = 0 ; A.length > Y ; Y++ )
        {
            System.out.println( A[ Y ] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, that `String` class *does* have a [method for that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

/edit
`Scanner#next` returns the next token of input. `Scanner`s tokenize the input they receive by whitespace, so `"The Little Pigs"` would be tokenized into `"The"`, `"Little"` and `"Pigs"` by calls to `next`. If you want the entire line, try `Scanner#nextLine`.